# Create a new pdf when the page height exceeded

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using iTextSharp 5 to generate a clothing label as a pdf file. I need to create a second pdf rather than creating a new page if the page height is exceeded. Is it possible? How to do this? Please help.

This is my code. I needed to continue this multi language text to an another pdf if it exceeds the page height. Page length is 110 mm. Sometimes multi language text is long.

This is the generated pdf:

[image: Resulting pdf]

```
protected void btnOpenLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, false);

    //iTextSharp.text.Font titreProgFont = FontFactory.GetFont("HELVETICA", 7, Font.NORMAL,BaseColor.RED);
    string fireWarning = "KEEP AWAY FROM FIRE";
    string madeinText = "Made in the U.K.";
    string sizeuk = "UK";

    string multiLanguageText = "This is a long multi language text. This should be continue to next page if the page height exceeded. This should happen automatically when using a very long text in pdfs";
    string lastLine = "Edge";
    string nextpageText="This text should be placed in next page";

    try
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("pdf")+"\\"+ "MnSLabel"+".pdf",FileMode.Create);
        float xpointValue = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(20);
        float ypointvalue = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(110);
        Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(xpointValue, ypointvalue);
        Document document = new Document(pageSize, 0, 0, 3, 0);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);

        document.AddAuthor("Chathu");
        document.Open();

        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        cb.BeginText();
        //first text by method calling
        iTextSharp.text.Font firewarningFont = FontFactory.GetFont("HELVETICA", 6, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);
        Chunk c1 = new Chunk();
        Phrase textPhrase = new Phrase();
        ColumnText ct1 = new ColumnText(cb);
        SetPDFColumnText(ct1,fireWarning,firewarningFont,c1,textPhrase,4,8,17,90,cb,5,Element.ALIGN_CENTER,Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        //end fire warning by method calling

        //made in text method calling
        iTextSharp.text.Font madein_textFont = FontFactory.GetFont("HELVETICA",4,Font.NORMAL,BaseColor.BLACK);
        SetPDFColumnText(ct1,madeinText,madein_textFont,c1,textPhrase,2,4,18,94,cb,5,Element.ALIGN_CENTER,Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        //end made in method calling

        //sizes uk
        iTextSharp.text.Font sizeUKFont = FontFactory.GetFont("HELVETICA", 4, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
        SetPDFColumnText(ct1,sizeuk,sizeUKFont,c1,textPhrase,5,45,15,84,cb,1,Element.ALIGN_CENTER,Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        //end size uk
        SetPDFColumnText(ct1, multiLanguageText , sizeUKFont, c1, textPhrase, 0, 2, 20, 1, cb, 1, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

        cb.EndText();

        //care symbols start
        PdfReader bgReader = new PdfReader(Server.MapPath("attachments") + "\\" + "CL1.pdf");
        PdfImportedPage bg = writer.GetImportedPage(bgReader, 1);
        float Scale = 0.25f;
        cb.AddTemplate(bg, Scale, 0, 0, Scale, 2, 130);
        //care symbols end

        //FIBER content

        document.Close();
        writer.Close();
        fs.Close();

        lblSuccess.Text = "Sample M&S Label saved to folder";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblSuccess.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}

public void SetPDFColumnText(ColumnText ct, string pdfText, iTextSharp.text.Font pdfFont,Chunk pdfChunk,Phrase pdfPhrase,float lowerleft_x,float lowerleft_y,float upperright_x,float upperright_y,PdfContentByte cb,float textLeading,int lineAlignment,int textAlignment) {
    float edge_lowerLeftY = 4;
    float edge_upperRightY = 2;
    int pdfCounter = 1;
    edge_lowerLeftY = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(edge_lowerLeftY);
    edge_upperRightY = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(edge_upperRightY);
    //ColumnText ct1 = new ColumnText(cb);
    lowerleft_x = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(lowerleft_x);
    lowerleft_y = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(lowerleft_y);
    upperright_x = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(upperright_x);
    upperright_y = iTextSharp.text.Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(upperright_y);
}
```

Comment: I haven't use the iTextSharp, but if is like any other libraries, when the height is >= of the max of the page, just create a new page for the document and use that page
Check this link: https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/faq/getting-started/itext-5-legacy/how-create-document-unequal-page-sizes `document.newPage();`

Comment: As you don't show how you create your pdf, it's difficult to explain what to change. Nonetheless, one option would be to generate the pdf as before, i.e. as one big pdf, and then split it into separate pages in a second pass.

Comment: Can I create an one big pdf when the page content is dynamic? It could be only a one page or maybe multiple.

Comment: iText allows creation of big documents easily. But you have chosen to work with `ColumnText`, i.e. you have chosen to take much of the layout work into your own hands. This gives you great flexibility at the price of having to do a lot of stuff manually that iText otherwise would automatically do for you under the hood.